# My code with all inputs besides a space before or after a number

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make my API accept street addresses. It works fine when trying something like "Street Address", but if I were to add a number anywhere within that, for example "123 Street Address" or "Street 123 Address", it's a bad request. I am a bit new to all of this and I am wondering if someone knows how I could fix this and why it's happening.

```
[HttpGet("address={streetAddress}"]
public ContentResult Index(string streetAddress)
{       
   return new ContentResult
   {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = streetAddress
   };
}
```

I would expect this to return "123 Shipping Street" if I used the URL `api/address=123%20Street%20Address` but instead I get HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

Comment: My apologies, I typed it wrong in the post.

Comment: I've tried this in a new .NET Core 2.1 web application and it works as expected without errors using a browser. Show us the controller and the entire url you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the request by post instead of get.